# JQuery - Every click on table changes the cell width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having some weird issue with widths of table cells. All I try to do, is to get the width of the table cell using .width() function, then set that width on the same cell in width attribute:

```
$table.find('tr:first td').each(function () {
    var actualWidth = $(this).width();
    $(this).attr("width", actualWidth);
});
```

Every time I do that, it gets a different width for some cells (Usually reduces one and increase another).

I saw a similar question from 2012:  [jQuery width() returning incorrect values on table cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13546865/jquery-width-returning-incorrect-values-on-table-cells)
But it's quite old and the accepted answer doesn't seem to work.

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/awolf/40pj1b2u/

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you reproduce in `fiddle` or `snippet`?

Comment: Attribute width for td is deprecated in html5, use css instead: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12881097/2674937

Comment: you are setting same width to same cell here

Comment: you do nothing in this code

Comment: I can't even begin to understand what the purpose of attempting this could be. What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: @Guruprasad Rao I added a fiddle.

Comment: @Esko I tried with css, same result.

Comment: When I'm adding a table via TinyMCE plugin, When you type into a cell, the cell grows with the text. I want to get that width and set it in an attribute.

Comment: Sorry, but for me this code has no sense...in the fiddle also nothing happens when I click into the table cells... you save the width value of the $(this) element and give it again to the same one.. for example: when you click on cell2, which has a width of 200px and you say, var1 = $(this).width() -> (that means cell2), than var1 has the value of 200px.. after that you give to the width attribute of cell2 the value of var1, what means you give him again his own width and no changes happen.. what is your idea of this code? please explain it to us...

Comment: Are you trying to change the width of the table, or are you just trying to get the value? Because right now you're changing the width. If you're wondering why setting the width to the width changes the width, it could be because there's more ways to interpret the width than .width();

Comment: @MrBuggy, See my comment above you. I added width to the cells in my fiddle, just to show you that I don't get the correct width with .width() and the cells width always changes.

Comment: @Goose I'm trying the get the actual width and then set it.

Answer (score 1):

I think there are two problems in one. All related to the table-cell display.

1. The use of border attribute (border="1") in the
   `<table>` probably messes up the width value when read. Probably the same when setting attr('width') value. In order to match the closest real value, you can use **innerWidth()** as @Adam P suggested.
2. Table cells width depends on the full available table width. In your jsfiddle sample, when expanding the table zone, cells' width are increasing. So, from each cell Width, you can compute the global table width, and apply it.

See this https://jsfiddle.net/piiantom/72dvm0v4/, taken from yours, with JS adjustments.
Table border can be changed, the JS still works

Answer (score 0):

I would consider this a bug.
My interpretation:
 When reading the width, it gets the content-width.
 When setting it, the box gets rendered and then the border set (taking 1px from content each time).
Same with .attr(), .prop(), and .width().

Have a look at box-sizing, .innerWidth() and .outerWidth()!